# How to use Storyboards with multiple segues to one view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

My app will use a simple login type selcector view controller, and from that it'll branch out to different view controllers, i.e. Sign Up, Sign In, and Sign In with Social networks. Now how do I add a segue from all of these to one single destination view controller. How do I add these multiple segues.

Comment: so, you are adding segues from LoginVC to others "Sign Up, Sign In, and Sign In with Social networks". connect with the segue in the same way from each one to your single destination CV.

Comment: Have you used three different buttons for this ?

Comment: The problem isn't branching out from one view controller, the problem is getting all those branches back to 1 view controller

Comment: And by back I mean single to another view controller ahead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every ViewController should have their own seque. To create, press "Ctrl" and move to the ViewController you want

[image]

And every ViewController should implement "prepareForSegue"

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[MyDestinationVC class]]) {
        //do something
        //Example
        MyDestinationVC *screen = (MyDestinationVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
        screen.someValue = self.sendedValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have segues between one view(LoginVC) to others (login, social login, etc...)
System already knows last viewcontroller from which you came to newer viewcontroller.
You just execute
`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` or put system barbuttons like `UIBarButtonSystemItemDone` to take care of dismissal by system itself
to go back.

Unless you have some other problem, this solution should work for you.